# jquery- how to run ajax in document ready?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to load information with ajax when my page loads but no information is displaying, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'ajax_load.php',              
      type: "post",          
      data: "artist=<?php echo $artist; ?>",
      dataType: 'html',                
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('#current_page').append("loading..");
          },
      success: finished(html),
   });
});

function finished(result) {
    $('#current_page').append(result);
};
```

ajax_load.php contains:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['artist'])) {
   $artist = $_POST['artist'];
   echo $artist;
}

echo "test";

?>
```

the html part of the page is fine

Comment: What is the html of the page with ajax?  Does `loading...` appear appropriately?

Comment: You are receiving `artist` from the post in ajax_load.php, but what populates the php variable `$artist` in `<?php echo $artist;?>` on the initial page load?

Comment: try debugging using a `failure` handler

Comment: Also, remove the trailing comma after `success: finished(html),`  Some browsers will trip over that.

Comment: Aloong with Michaels remark, I'd try echoing $_POST instead of "test" to see what's being received by ajaz_load.php.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the value of the `success` option to be a reference to a function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'ajax_load.php',              
      type: "post",          
      data: "artist=<?php echo $artist; ?>",
      dataType: 'html',                
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('#current_page').append("loading..");
          },
      success: finished //Change to this
   });
});
```

Currently you are setting `success` to the return value of `finished`, which is `undefined`. If you check your browser console you will likely be getting an error along the lines of "undefined is not a function".

Comment: Thanks very much :) - I started off learning C so I didn't expect to use a function in this way. Cheers!